# Include question title when sharing to Twitter from Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, twitter

I am a user of the SE Android app; I recently came across the share feature and  liked it a lot. I have tried using it with Twitter, but I feel in addition to sharing the question URL it should also include the question title in the share. Currently the share only includes a link to the question and does not have any detail of the question itself.

Though a share user can include details of question himself, it would be more intuitive and user friendly to just tap and share entire question with title of question and link.

It will improve sharing ratio via Twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tl;dr:* there's a question at the end of this answer, help me answer it.

I've thought about this *a lot*. When sharing something on Android you can fill info in two fields: `EXTRA_SUBJECT` (typically a title), and `EXTRA_TEXT` (typically a message). We're currently putting the question's title in the `EXTRA_SUBJECT` field and the URL to the question in the `EXTRA_TEXT` field. Different apps react differently to the two pieces of data. Some just use the `EXTRA_TEXT`, some use both.

The main reason we haven't put the title in the message field and just combined the two is a purely selfish one: I routinely use the "Copy to clipboard" option in the Share dialog and it not just copying the URL is one of my biggest Android pet peeves. Most other apps do what you are asking for in this scenario, copy both the title and URL to the clipboard (since that's also what would be sent over as the tweet body).

Now to make matters a lot worse, let's look at what it looks like when you try to Share to Facebook, G+, and Twitter right now:

[image: Social network triptych]

As you can see, they all react differently to the share request. **Facebook** and **Google+** actually ignore the fact that what we told them to share was the URL, and embedded the URL in the post instead alongside a empty by default caption for it ("Write something...) -- **Twitter** on the other hand does the simplest operation and flat out jams the URL we're trying to share into your tweet.

Here's where it gets worse. Let's hit "Tweet" on that draft and see what it looks like now:

[image: Twitter]

Look at that! Twitter actually one-boxes/embeds the question into the tweet, while still showing the URL of it as the tweet contents, something that's not visible to you at all while you're actually composing the tweet.

Anyway, in summation: [Everything is not coming up milhouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M67E9mpwBpM) -- Sharing kind of sucks on Android. However, if we can get this question answered (post in the comments!) we'll do it:

If we change Share to share the title of the question alongside the URL to it, we'll get duplicated question titles on Facebook, Google+, and the expanded view of a tweet. We'd also have "Share to Clipboard" have both the URL and the title on it. Would this be preferred to what we have now?

Comment: Oh really its not necessary. I didnt expanded my tweet to next level. Really awsome design. +1.

Comment: @Pushpak it's still not perfect because people won't see the actual expanded view unless they click on the tweet, so your timeline will just have a tweet of a URL -- It'd be more likely to be clicked on by people if it was a more interesting tweet (which included the title), I think.

Comment: Actually url is coded with numbers when we share. Can't we shorten it and keep atleast 5-10 words of question in url itself. I think it happens if we click on question on web interface.

Comment: @Pushpak a URL, no matter how long, is considered 22 characters in a tweet since Twitter rewrites it to t.co -- yes, the website includes title when sharing to Twitter but the website can do Twitter specific sharing, the app can't.

Comment: Let me rephrase while visiting this question url says [http---/include-question-title-when-sharing-to-twitter-from-android-app] and while sharing url becomes [http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250088/282585]  Now i think if while sharing same pattern like website is used then url itself will specify title. What you say

Comment: By the way also keep in mind that editing question title by moderator will effect above situation; we need some masking or permalink kind of feature to make it work.

Comment: YouTube app shares their video with title "Watch "`{video_title}`" on YouTube" and message "`{video_title}` (up to 75 characters) and `{shortened_url}` (with format `https://youtu.be/{video_id}`). Perhaps duplication of title is not that bad? In which, there's a follow-up question: which is more convenient for user, deleting the duplicate title, or copy-paste the title?